# Why do things fall down?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

The alien mothership in [Independence Day: Resurgence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day:_Resurgence) is so huge that it covers a considerable part of the Earth's surface. A point is made that it even exerts its own gravity. Before landing it seems to move across a part of the Earth's surface at a relatively low distance, wreaking havoc by pulling buildings, ships, and other large objects up into the sky by its gravitational force. When the alien mothership finally stops, everything formerly attracted by the vessel's gravitation falls back to the ground. David, a protagonist, comments:

> "What goes up must come down."

Why is that? Has the gravitational force by the alien mothership disappeared upon landing? Even if so, was David expecting this effect?

Comment: @Radhil: The difference is: Yours doesn't form complete sentences.

Answer (score 2):

"If you push something hard enough, it will fall over"
--Fudd's first law of opposition.

When something "falls" i.e. is attracted to the Earth by its gravity, technically the Earth is also attracted to the object. It's just that in the case of small things like pencils and automobiles, the force applied by the smaller object is infinitesimal. In the case of a ship the size of the aliens', that force is large enough to actually enter into the calculations.

To summarize, they have it wrong - they're likely mixing up the gravity exerted by an object that massive, and whatever process it used to NEGATE that gravity, to allow it to float in mid-air above a planet and not crash into it. Theoretically, a field that negates the effect of gravity by the Earth on the ship should also negate the effect of the mass of the ship on the Earth. So it should NOT be attracting objects until that gravity-cancelling effect is shut down.

But once it is shut off... woo.

Picture if you will the effect on the earth if the moon were moved to only a few thousand miles away.  Tides alone would be catastrophic. I was always amazed the effect of the massive tonnage of the alien ships from the first movie would have on the Earth's orbit and rotation - I shudder to think the effect of a Mothership crashing, at speed, yet.

Comment: One aditional thing also that needs to be kept in mind: The mothership has less mass than earth thus less gravitational pull by its own. Thus objects are attracted to earth more than to the ship (technological circumvations excepted)

Comment: Yes, but "loose" objects could conceivably still be attracted to the ship - water is attracted to the moon, which is how tides occur.  Again, the mass of the ship is such that its gravitic effect on Earth is large enough to be part of the math. When you drop a pen, the distance the Earth moves towards the pen is immeasurably small.  Not so with the mtoerhship.